# DataColumn in DataTable not found by name

Tags: c#, datatable, datacolumn

I'm reading from a CSV file where the first line is the header row. All column names are read and put into a table like this:

```
foreach (var item in lines[0].Split(';').Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)))
        {
            table.Columns.Add(item.Trim(), typeof(string));
        }
```

Everything seams correct, except when I try to read from the table again.
Most of the columns are read, except one.

I have tried to debug and write a message for this column, but it does NOT enter into that function (see image below). (The if statement return false)

[image]

I have tried about everything now, including checking the Locale on the table.

Header line:

```
document title;DocRef;DocRevNo;DocRevDt;RevisionObject;TransRef;Trans Status;DocOrigin;DocRefClient;RespActualDt;First TransDate;Last Update
```

**EDIT:**

I have found out that first byte is a strange one...

```
[0]: 65279 ''
[1]: 100 'd'
[2]: 111 'o'
[3]: 99 'c'
[4]: 117 'u'
[5]: 109 'm'
[6]: 101 'e'
[7]: 110 'n'
[8]: 116 't'
[9]: 32 ' '
[10]: 116 't'
[11]: 105 'i'
[12]: 116 't'
[13]: 108 'l'
[14]: 101 'e'
```

Anyone that knows how to remove that byte (If it exist)?

Comment: could you just add your first line from csv ?

Comment: I have repeated your code in LinqPad. Everything works for me. Have you tried to look at every ColumnName? I mean is the column exist? Sometimes I met this bug. But in my case, it was one letter but in different languages. F.e. letter 'c' on English and 'с' on Russian looks same, but it differences letters.

Comment: Very good point. The source is from France, I'm on a norwegian culture... Initial tests on that did not solve it, but I will investigate more...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution.
The start of the line contained a hidden charakter (65279). By running the text through this function, it removed the problem:

```
    protected string CleanInput(string input)
    {
        var imp = (input ?? "");
        var removeChars = new Char[] { (Char)65279 };
        imp = new String(imp.ToCharArray().Where(c => !removeChars.Contains(c)).ToArray());
        return imp;
    }
```